# What is Kotetsu trying to parody with the fundamentals of photography?

Tags: hayate-no-gotoku

What is Kotetsu trying to parody in this scene from chapter 495?
Apparently its really old.

[image: fundamentals]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a reference to the manga [Kyuukyoku Chojin R](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=44207) (究極超人あ〜る), a gag manga running from 1985-1987 published in Shuukan Shounen Sunday (the same magazine *Hayate* runs in) about a robot student named R who joins a photography club.

More specifically, it's a reference to the somewhat well-known scene in the first chapter of volume 8, titled 「これは基本だ」 ("These are the fundamentals"), in which a couple club members get into an argument about what the most important principles are to follow during photography. Here's the relevant 2-page spread (click for full-size):

[image: reference image]

You can see that the third panel on the left page is obviously a similar posture to the one in the image from *Hayate*. The text there and in the next panel translates to:

> These are the fundamentals of photography!
>
> "Triumph through backlighting!"
>
> "Divide the world in thirds!"
>
> "Never use direct sunlight!"
>
> "Overhead empty margins are the enemy!"

This is basically exactly what Kotetsu says as well. I don't have access to an untranslated version of *Hayate no Gotoku* chapter 495, but it's clearly the same principles being said, and quite possibly the exact same dialogue in Japanese.

Incidentally, this scene itself has a reference to [Kodak Tri-X film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodak_Tri-X). The right page contains the phrase 「トライＸで万全」 ("Perfection through Tri-X"), which is used a bit satirically to refer to people who believe that film quality alone will lead to great pictures. This part of the scene is probably a bit more well-known, an has been referenced as well, most notably in Genshiken Nidaime:

[image: Genshiken reference]